# How to create a procedure where condition is from two tables?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a procedure that looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `transformare_in_imprumut`()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE stoc_actual INT(4);
    SELECT stoc INTO stoc_actual FROM carti WHERE 
        carti.idCarte=rezervari.idCarte;
    IF(stoc_actual >0) THEN
        UPDATE carti set stoc=stoc-1 WHERE carti.idCarte=rezervari.idCarte;
        INSERT INTO imprumuturi(idCarte) 
            SELECT idCarte FROM rezervari;
    ELSE
        UPDATE carti set stoc=stoc+1;
    END IF;
END;
```

The problem is I want to update the imprumuturi table when the WHERE condition is met.But this procedure does not work,because I am comparing two values from two different tables.My question is :how to get two values from two tables and compare them in the WHERE condition.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share some sample data for both of the table and expected sample data post procedure call.

Comment: You need to join the two tables. But I don't understand what you expect to be stored into `stoc_actual` if there are multiple rows that match between the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple rows that match between the tables you can't store them all in a single variable.

You could use a cursor to loop through all the matching rows, but a simpler way is to put the `JOIN` in the `UPDATE`. A `LEFT JOIN` will allow you to do the correct update depending on whether the row has a match in the other table.

```
UPDATE carti
LEFT JOIN rezervari ON carti.idCarte = reservari.idCart
SET carti.stoc = IF(reservari.idCart IS NULL, stoc+1, stoc-1);

INSERT INTO imprumuturi (idCart)
SELECT idCarte FROM rezervari;
```